# In Excel, how can I set a cell to automatically update to today's date?

Tags: excel, validation

I understand how to set the format of the cell, but I want to prevent users from typing anything at all because they always end up typing the wrong format. When they click in the date cell, is it possible for the date - today's date - to automatically fill in?

Answer (score 0):

On the Formulas ribbon, look to the far right and click Calculation Options. On the dropdown list, verify that Automatic is selected.

This will force your cell to update automatically.

Please refer to the following link:
[https://www.pryor.com/blog/why-is-your-excel-formula-not-calculating/#:~:text=Check%20for%20Automatic%20Recalculation,you%20change%20a%20cell%20value](https://www.pryor.com/blog/why-is-your-excel-formula-not-calculating/#:%7E:text=Check%20for%20Automatic%20Recalculation,you%20change%20a%20cell%20value).

EDIT:
Don't lock the cell, select you cells, set the format to your desired format (right mouse click => format cells), go to data in your Ribbon, then select data validation under "data tools", set the format to data and set it to "lesser than" > "=NOW()"

Comment: The column is a date column, so each cell is already set to reflect a date. The problem is even when the cell's are set to a specific format, for example dd-mm-yyyy, someone can still write over it as mm-dd-yyyy and it gets all messed up. I want the cell to auto-fill with today's date so no one has to type anything or even better..can't type anything in.

Comment: you can use data validation to force a certain date format: https://www.contextures.com/exceldatavalidationdates.html

Comment: and you can use this to lock the cell: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4078-excel-make-cell-read-only.html

Comment: I figured that would be how to do it but I simply can't get it to work. I think i'm putting the formula in the wrong place or something. Do you know the steps to do this in a step by step way?

Comment: Don't lock the cell, select you cells, set the format to your desired format (right mouse click => format cells), go to data in your Ribbon, then select data validation under "data tools", set the format to data and set it to "lesser than" > "=NOW()"

Comment: Thank you i'll try that

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any further issues